# Frobenius condition

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Suppose X and Y are two unit length vector fields on a Riemannian manifold which are orthogonal at each point. Is it true that the lie bracket of X, Y belongs to the span of the vector fields at each point in the manifold?
Is there a way to prove or disprove this without going into local coordinate expressions.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick any manifold of dimension 3 or higher and any two non-vanishing vector fields that do not satisfy the Frobenius condition. Define a Riemannian metric such that the vector fields are orthonormal.

Comment: Thank you. But what would happen if I impose $X= \frac{\nabla \phi}{|\nabla \phi|}$ and $Y = \frac{\nabla \psi}{|\nabla \psi|}$ so that the vector fields have explicit information about metric. Do you suspect that the answer is again negative?

Comment: I don't see why this should be any different. I suggest trying to construct a counterexample with the standard flat metric.

Comment: With the standard flat metric, any affine function $\phi$ will have gradient perpendicular to that of a function $\psi$ just when their gradients commute, so you get some examples. However, for Morse $\phi$ you find that there are no possibilities for $\psi$, because there are no integrals of motion of the gradient vector field.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the two fields are orthonormal or not has nothing to do with integrability:
After doing Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization you have the same integrability property as before, since $[X,fY] = f[X,Y] + X(f).Y$ etc.